# Routing a static folder in public

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-5.4

I have purchased a page builder from [Themeforest](https://themeforest.net/) called Flatpack Page Builder. According to it's installation notes

> Installing the HTML Builder is simply a matter uploading the "builder" folder to a server/hosting account. Once uploaded, point your browser to builder's directory and the builder will work. 
>   For example: www.yoursite.com/builder

So I've uploaded it to `laravelapp/public/page-builder` and is accessible through the route `mysite.com/page-builder`. How do I route it so I can restrict it to be only accessible by authenticated users, particularly by the admin only.

So right now I have this route

```
Route::get('super/page-builder/builder', array('as' => 'page-builder', 'uses' => function () {
    return File::get(public_path() . '/page-builder/index.html');
}));
```

It works and it is returned but all the images, css, and js files cannot be loaded which is located in the same folder

```
public/
   page-builder/
      css/
      js/
      images/
      index.html
      iupload.php
      preview.php
      publish.php
      save.php
```

I really need help.

Comment: I *don't think* this is possible in the way you're describing. What exactly is "Flatpack Page Builder" ? It's a good idea to extract the bits you need and build views using the blade syntax and protect those routes/groups

Comment: @AndyHolmes it's a drag n drop html page builder. I'm gonna use it as an email template builder for our automated emailing system.

Comment: @AndyHolmes you can try it here http://themeforest.pixfort.com/landing/flatpack/builder/

Comment: Cheers for the link. I would take the code, put it in a view and protect the route that serves the view

Comment: See Protecting Routes : https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication

Comment: @NiekvanderMaaden but it isn't a route, it's a directory

Comment: @AndyHolmes Aye, missed that part!

Comment: @AndyHolmes I'd like to do that and put it in a view but there's a lot of files that the index.html is dependent on. And also the functions of the page-builder is written not as a class, but just a basic php code. see my update in the question

Comment: I'm not seeing the issue though, you can still reference these files

Comment: @AndyHolmes which files do i transfer in view? only `index.html` right? and all the other files will remain in public?

Comment: Well you can put the PHP code in a blade.php file if you so wish. That would take them out of the public folder. What you're trying to do is achievable